# How to read from particular header in opencsv?

Tags: java, opencsv

I have a csv file. I want to extract particular column from it.For example:
Say, I have csv:

```
id1,caste1,salary,name1
63,Graham,101153.06,Abraham
103,Joseph,122451.02,Charlie
63,Webster,127965.91,Violet
76,Smith,156150.62,Eric
97,Moreno,55867.74,Mia
65,Reynolds,106918.14,Richard
```

How can i use opencsv to read only data from header caste1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built in functionality in opencsv for reading from a column by name.

The [official FAQ example](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) has the following example on how to read from a file:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
String [] nextLine;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
   // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
   System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");
}
```

You simply fetch the value in second column for each row by accesing the row with `nextLine[1]` (remember, arrays indices are zero based).

So, in your case you could simply read from the second line:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
String [] nextLine;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
   System.out.println(nextLine[1]);
}
```

---

For a more sophisticated way of determining the column index from its header, refer to [the answer from Scott Conway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31440044/1421925).

Comment: I have to fetch from header name(caste1), not from index..what should i do?

Comment: @user2080429 I don't think this behaviour is built into OpenCSV. Use `reader.readNext()` to read the first line, determine which index it has, and use my solution.

Comment: @Magnilex can I get value by header name directly,

Comment: @PranayKumbhalkar There seems to be no direct support for this, but check out Scotts answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/31440044/1421925

Comment: @Magnilex The code written by Scotts not works, but concept used by scotts works for me. First he get header position and get value on particular position from array

Answer (score 10):

Magnilex and Sparky are right in that CSVReader does not support reading values by column name.  But that being said there are two ways you can do this.

Given that you have the column names and the default CSVReader reads the header you can search the first the header for the position then use that from there on out;

```
private int getHeaderLocation(String[] headers, String columnName) {
   return Arrays.asList(headers).indexOf(columnName);
}
```

so your method would look like (leaving out a lot of error checks you will need to put in)

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
String [] nextLine;
int columnPosition;

nextLine = reader.readNext();
columnPosition = getHeaderLocation(nextLine, "castle1");

while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null && columnPosition > -1) {
   // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
   System.out.println(nextLine[columnPosition]);
}
```

I would only do the above if you were pressed for time and it was only one column you cared about.  That is because openCSV can convert directly to an object that has the variables the same as the header column names using the `CsvToBean` class and the `HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy`.

So first you would define a class that has the fields (and really you only need to put in the fields you want - extras are ignored and missing ones are null or default values).

```
public class CastleDTO {
   private int id1;
   private String castle1;
   private double salary;
   private String name1;

   // have all the getters and setters here....
}
```

Then your code would look like

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<CastleDTO> castleStrategy = new HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<CastleDTO>();
CsvToBean<CastleDTO> csvToBean = new CsvToBean<CastleDTO>();

List<CastleDTO> castleList = csvToBean.parse(castleStrategy, reader);

for (CastleDTO dto : castleList) {
   System.out.println(dto.getCastle1());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [opencsv docs](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#even_quicker_start):

> Starting with version 4.2, there’s another handy way of reading CSV files that doesn’t even require creating special classes. If your CSV file has headers, you can initialize a CSVReaderHeaderAware instance and read values as a map:

```java
  reader = new CSVReaderHeaderAware(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
  record = reader.readMap();
```

`.readMap()` will return a single record. You need to call `.readMap()` repeatedly to get all the records until you get `null` when it runs to the end (or to the first empty line), e.g.:

```java
Map<String, String> values;

while ((values = reader.readMap()) != null) {

    // consume the values here

}
```

The class also has another constructor which allows more customization, e.g.:

```java
CSVReaderHeaderAware reader = new CSVReaderHeaderAware(
        new InputStreamReader(inputStream),
        0,      // skipLines
        parser, // custom parser
        false,  // keep end of lines
        true,   // verify reader
        0,      // multiline limit
        null    // null for default locale
);
```

A possible downside is that since the reader is lazy it does not offer a record count, therefore, if you need to know the total number (for example to display correct progress information), then you'll need to use another reader just for counting lines.

See also:

- [CSVReaderHeaderAwareBuilder](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.opencsv/opencsv/latest/com/opencsv/CSVReaderHeaderAwareBuilder.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had a task to remove several columns from existing csv, example of csv:

```
FirstName, LastName, City, County, Zip
Steve,Hopkins,London,Greater London,15554
James,Bond,Vilnius,Vilniaus,03250
```

I needed only FirstName and LastName columns with values and it is very important that order should be the same - default rd.readMap() does not preserve the order, code for this task:

```
        String[] COLUMN_NAMES_TO_REMOVE = new String[]{"", "City", "County", "Zip"};
        CSVReaderHeaderAware rd = new CSVReaderHeaderAware(new StringReader(old.csv));
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter((new FileWriter(new.csv)),
                CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR, CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER, CSVWriter.NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER, CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END);

        // let's get private field
        Field privateField = CSVReaderHeaderAware.class.getDeclaredField("headerIndex");
        privateField.setAccessible(true);
        Map<String, Integer> headerIndex = (Map<String, Integer>) privateField.get(rd);

        // do ordering in natural order - 0, 1, 2 ... n
        Map<String, Integer> sortedInNaturalOrder = headerIndex.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                        (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));

        // let's get headers in natural order
        List<String> headers = sortedInNaturalOrder.keySet().stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

        // let's remove headers
        List<String> removedColumns = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(COLUMN_NAMES_TO_REMOVE));
        headers.removeAll(removedColumns);
        // save column names           
        writer.writeNext(headers.toArray(new String[headers.size()]));
   
        List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, String> values;
        while ((values = rd.readMap()) != null) {
            for (String key : headers) {
                keys.add(values.get(key));
                if (keys.size() == headers.size()) {
                    String[] itemsArray = new String[headers.size()];
                    itemsArray = keys.toArray(itemsArray);
                    // save values                       
                    writer.writeNext(itemsArray);
                    keys.clear();
                }
            }
        }
        writer.flush();
```

Output:

```
FirstName, LastName
Steve,Hopkins
James,Bond
```

Answer (score -4):

Looking at the [javadoc](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/)

if you create a CSVReader object, then you can use the method .readAll to pull the entire file. It returns a List of String[], with each String[] representing a line of the file. So now you have the tokens of each line, and you only want the second element of that, so split them up as they have been nicely given to you with delimiters. And on each line you only want the second element, so:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String data = "63,Graham,101153.06,Abraham";
    String result[] = data.split(",");
    System.out.print(result[1]);
}
```